# What's the name of the header shrinking animation in Samsung's One UI

Tags: interaction-design, animation, microinteractions

I'm curious about the name of this behavior, I remember reading it in a design blog a few months ago but completely forgot about it, algo OnePlus implemented something similar in OxygenOS 11 and Google is doing something similar with Android 12

[image: This is what I'm talking about]

Comment: It would be good if you can describe the specific context of the interaction (or if it is a general UI pattern) so it will help narrow down the answer since interactions can also be broken down into micro-interactions.

Answer (score 0):

The effect is described in W3Schools and also a couple of other places as [Shrink/Resize Header on Scroll](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_shrink_header_scroll.asp).

It seems to be used to save display space for sticky headers that normally implement a bigger font size and padding, but doesn't need to be so prominent once the user starts moving away from it.